# Where are the "mod_wsgi" files on Ubuntu?

Tags: apache2, uwsgi

I am trying to install a system called INGInious. The [installation instructions](https://inginious.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install_doc/installation.html)  are mainly for CENTOS, and I try to see how to adapt them to Ubuntu. In particular, in the Apache configuration (at the end of the page), they say that I have to add the following VirtualHost entry to the Apache2 configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my_inginious_domain
    LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py35.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

    WSGIScriptAlias / "/usr/bin/inginious-webapp"
    WSGIScriptReloading On

    Alias /static /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/inginious/frontend/static

    <Directory "/usr/bin">
        <Files "inginious-webapp">
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    <DirectoryMatch "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/inginious/frontend/static">
        Require all granted
    </DirectoryMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is, I do not find these files on my system.

How can I find the correct path to write in the `LoadModule` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to find a path  if it does not do it on its own during install then `a2enmod module_to_load` and `Apache` does it all for you. I would think it is the first package listed unless wanting the `Python` 3 version, as it seems too match the naming of the modules I have installed in the past on `Apache`. I would think they did not change the name much in `Ubuntu`

```
root@buster-raspi:~# apt-cache search mod_wsgi
libapache2-mod-wsgi - Python WSGI adapter module for Apache
libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 - Python 3 WSGI adapter module for Apache
python-okasha - trivial WSGI web framework for Python
python-okasha-examples - trivial WSGI web framework for Python (examples)
pycsw-wsgi - WSGI Apache CSW service based on pycsw
```

Comment: So if I use "a2enmod", I can just delete the line beginning with 'LoadModule "?

Comment: Yes when you enable the module it is loaded by the program. Should not be necessary I always see "enabling the module, reloading `Apache`" in the messages any time I install one. That was the old way before they did it with the configuration scripts. This is why I said if not done for you.

Comment: Thanks, I removed this line and it worked

Comment: You are welcome nice to read it worked for you.